# Describe Class and Class inheritance using Mathematical notation for function or set

Tags: class, oop, math, machine-learning, notation

In network theory, you can describe a graph or network as a function of nodes or vertices and edges ie, `G(e,v)`.

Similarly in machine learning, you can describe a neural network as

```
 ̂ =(,) where  is an input,   is a set of parameters and ̂  is a prediction of y.
```

Is there any convention for describing a class (from object-oriented programming) in mathematical notation or terms?  In particular, I'm trying to describe the concept of inheritance in mathematical terms.

Take the example of a truck class that inherits from the vehicle class. The truck has all the characteristics of a vehicle but some customization.  All trucks are vehicles so one might say that trucks are a subset of vehicles.  However, the properties of the trucks exceed those of vehicles so not sure how to handle that using set notation.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Mathematical notation is sort of arbitrary. You can, if you feel like it, just make it up. In any case, here's the Liskov Substition Principle: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle if that is *mathy* enough for you. This like is a better fit for [cs.se]. Also, there is always [type theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory), since classes are better thought of as *types* really, not functions or sets. Or you could just learn Haskell...

Comment: UML is a formal way of talking about classes. It isn't mathematical, but is formal enough that it might lend itself to a more mathematical formulation. I am skeptical that the resulting abstraction would be terribly useful.